# How to set up https to nginx docker container (laradock)?

Tags: docker, nginx, https, certbot, laradock

I'd like to ask for some directions on how to set **https** in nginx using docker container. I'm working with laradock which comes with **certbot** container, but even though I've tried a lot of solutions none of them worked to me. To make the task even harder the documentation is very poor.

I'm looking for a solution that solves the problem not necessarily using certbot.

Comment: Can you provide the solution you have tried and the errors you received?

Comment: yeah of course, I implemented the https on the server using this tutorial: https://poweruphosting.com/blog/secure-nginx-with-lets-encrypt/ works like a charm, but when trying to do the same in a dockerized nginx it doesn't work so well.

Comment: currently I'm trying to install everything inside the container to test if it work, but when I try to create the certificate using certbot I'm having trouble in access the /.well-known/acme-challenge/ (403). maybe something in nginx server file config.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL certificate on local Laradock Nginx project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904510/ssl-certificate-on-local-laradock-nginx-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same challenge today and found this resource to be really helpful:

Setup LetsEncrypt with Laradock by ChillBits
https://chillbits.com/2021/06/24/setup-letsencrypt-with-laradock/