# SSL certificate on local Laradock Nginx project

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, laradock

I need your help to set my Laradock (with Docker) using Nginx and SSL "fake" certificate on my local machine.

I have no idea how to setup it. Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: This [project](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) might help ease of acquiring ssl certificate. I didn't use docker or php myself, but you might found solution afterward. Note: you can generate cert `.crt` and `.key` files from such tool which might be using with your script. Regarding to nginx setup, try search for `ssl_certificate`, `ssl_certificate_key` and `ssl_*` for bunch of setting up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable SSL with the current version of laradock (as of Nov 2019) with a self signed certificate you must enable it in the nginx settings. Inside the folder nginx/sites remove the comments below line 6 "# For https" :

```
# For https
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;
```

restart nginx : `docker-compose restart nginx` 
and you're ready.

If google-chrome complains you can enable the flag at `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`  to allow even invalid certificates.

Comment: I've uncommented the lines but it still doesn't work. Is there another, undocumented step here?

Answer (score 2):

The solution given only allows for https://localhost, however you might need to generate your own when using custom domain pointing to localhost, e.g https://testing.dev

I've written a gist to this — https://gist.github.com/r0lodex/0fe03fc8d22241d79cba65107b30868b

Hopefully this will help those who are still searching.

Comment: Should I be doing this in my docker container? A lot of this stuff is over my head currently.

Comment: @ladidaadi in the container where nginx is served.

Comment: How do I then import that into my Keychain if it was created inside of a container?

Comment: If it's in a container, it should be in your disk as well. You should be able to find it